# Can NHibernate QueryOver have a SQL-where statement?

Tags: nhibernate, queryover

I'm new to Nhibernate. My problem is that I want to narrow down a query by using a column that is not included in my entity (ie hbm). I want to do something like this:

```
Session.QueryOver<MyEntity>()
    .SQL_Where("MyFlag = 1")
```

Since I have no use of that flag later I don't want to include it to the entity

I know I can use:

```
Session
    .CreateSQLQuery("SELECT A,B,C FROM ENTITY WHERE MyFlag = 1")
    .SetResultTransformer(Transformers.AliasToBean<MyEntity>())
    .List<MyEntity>();
```

It would be nice to use QueryOver<>(), it's more safe if a column is added etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may be able to use filters:-

Put a filter on your mappings class definition, however this will affect ALL returned rows

e.g.

```
<class name="Domain.Model.MyEntity, Domain.Model" table="MyTable" 
       where="(MyFlag=1)">
    ...
</class>
```

or it may be possible to use conditional filters with QueryOver

```
<filter-def name="SetMyFlag">
    <filter-param name=":flag" type="System.Int"/>
</filter-def>

<class name="Domain.Model.MyEntity, Domain.Model" table="MyTable">
   ...
  <filter name="SetMyFlag" condition="(MyFlag=:flag)"/>
</class>
```

and use:-

```
session.EnableFilter("SetMyFlag").SetParameter("flag", 1);
session.QueryOver<MyEntity>();
```

Although I have never use conditional filters with unmapped columns so this may not work!

Comment: Can I ask a question did you use the `EnableFilter`? If so did you try it without the `<filter-param ..>` and using just `session.EnableFilter("SetMyFlag")` without chaining the `setParameter(...)`. I am curious that's all!